# Why am I getting error when using setAttribute() every time I type it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am using Vanilla JavaScript, and I am having trouble using setAttribute(). It is giving me errors like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute'). Every time I try to use it. I am trying to make a challenge without using a lot of HTML just CSS and JS. Here is the code.

### HTML and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Grid</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            #navbar div div {
                margin:auto;
            }

            #home:hover {
                color: red;
            }

            img {
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Navbar-->
        <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar">
            <div class="row" style="background-color:#eeeeee; height:3rem;">
                <div class="col-3 nav-items">Home</div>
                <div class="col-3 nav-items"><a>Link 1</a></div>
                <div class="col-3 nav-items"><a>Link 2</a></div>
                <div class="col-3 nav-items"><a>Link 3</a></div>             
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Image Grid-->
        <h2 >
            Image Grid        
        </h2>

        <div  style="margin-top:50px;" class="container">
            <div class="row" id="grid">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Picture 1
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Add Penguin
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Column
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Column
                    </p>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Column
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Column
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Add Goat
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img3/1551795199-559abd90f483a62b8e3fe9f3.png">
                    <p>
                        Column
                    </p>
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

### JS

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "Picture 0";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerHTML = "Picture 1";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[2].innerHTML = "Picture 2";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[3].innerHTML = "Picture 3";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[4].innerHTML = "Picture 4";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[5].innerHTML = "Picture 5";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[6].innerHTML = "Picture 6";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[7].innerHTML = "Picture 7";
        
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[2].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[3].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[4].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[5].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[6].style.textAlign = "center";
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[7].style.textAlign = "center";
         
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].src = "https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img9/fa1fa2b572ae453bb177587166ac7fa9-56116697f483a6229787d736.png";
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[6].src = "https://oyoclass.s3.amazonaws.com/post/img8/80599bc8945a408aa413cb195e19d6e0-56116697f483a6229787d736.jpeg";
        
        window.onload = function () {
            var linkEl = document.querySelector("#home");
            linkEl.setAttribute("href", "http://oyopages.com/p/61b8ab61666e4dc7d5f630e0.html");
        }
window.onload = function () {
    var el = document.querySelector("#home");
    el.setAttribute("href", "http://oyopages.com/p/61b8ab61666e4dc7d5f630e0.html");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If the `#home` element isn't found, you'll get an error because `el` is null.

Comment: So add a check `if (el) { ... }`

Comment: Please show us the part of your HTML where the #home element is defined. It should look something like this `<a href="some-url" id="home">Home</a>`.

Comment: Add the HTML code as well please. This isn't enough context to give a definite answer.

Comment: The error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')

Answer (score 0):

Your code work. Take a look in working example with your code. Element not found is always a sign that the element for running the script is not present.

```js
window.onload = function () { 
  var el = document.querySelector("#home"); 
  
  el.setAttribute("href", "http://oyopages.com/p/61b8ab61666e4dc7d5f630e0.html");
  console.log(el)
}
```

```html
<a id="home">HOME</a>
```